# Finder shows sizes greyed out and folders empty

Tags: macos, finder

In Lion, Finder shows sizes greyed out and when I open folders, they seem empty.

Upon "Get Info": they also look full with normal sized files.

WHy? How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? That would help me!

Comment: Did you try to switch views in the Finder window? Does it change anything?

Answer (score 2):

As best as I can tell, the file sizes are greyed out while Finder works to calculate the current size of the folder.  If you wait a moment and let Finder works its magic, you'll see the file sizes appear in the usual black font.

Answer (score 0):

How about hidden files? Some files are so called system files and they are made invisible for you own safety. Some files even tend to grow larger the longer you use your Mac. How much disk space are we talking about? Maybe a screenshot like Allan suggested?