# What does it mean when a size is greyed out in Finder?

Tags: finder, macos

Some sizes are greyed out in Finder in El Capitan. How come? What does it mean?

Comment: A screenshot might be helpful to clarify exactly what you're referring to. Are any of the other details greyed out?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32132/finder-shows-sizes-greyand ed-out-and-folders-empty and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56572/in-finder-the-file-size-is-dimmed

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to Finder still calculating the size of the item shown, such as by still enumerating the contents of a folder or package.  ACL also cause this:

- [Files Greyed out in Finder - Potential extended attributes issue?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163939/files-greyed-out-in-finder-potential-extended-attributes-issue)?